# Alias command not found when running .bashrc

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal

I'm trying to do the simplest of shell aliases like I always use to do.

Here's my .bashrc (and same happened with ZSH and .zshrc) for instance :

```
alias ll=“ls -al”
alias edit_http=“open -e /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf”
```

and here's my $PATH variable :

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

When I open a new terminal window I get this :

```
-bash: alias: -al”: not found
-bash: alias: -e: not found
-bash: alias: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf”: not found
```

Here's my ls -al result of .bashrc :

```
-rwxr-xr-x@   1 ed    staff     78 Mar 17 03:55 .bashrc
```

Strangely I can type this into Terminal and it works :

```
alias ll="ls -al"
```

But not from within the .bashrc file.

Any suggestions ?  I've checked so many forum entries and nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like something went wrong during copying the alias into your .bashrc.

You ended up with 'wrong' quotation mark. Replace `“` with `"`and it should work. `“` is unicode but you require ascii quotation marks. For testing you can use this .bashrc

```
# bashrc example
# won't work
alias ll=“ls -al”
# will work
alias la="ls -al"
```

And with this code you can verify your problem:

```
$ source .bashrc
-bash: alias: -al”: not found
$ ll
-bash: “ls: command not found
$ la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 alneuman  staff    68 Mar 17 12:18 .
drwxrwxrwx+ 70 alneuman  staff  2380 Mar 17 12:18 ..
```

Have a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109784) at unix.stackexchange. Somebody had the same issue. Brave new unicode world ;)

Comment: That was it.  Thanks so much!  Your post allowed me to see what was happening.  I was using "open -e" and TextEdit to edit the .bashrc file and the Substitutions - Smart Quotes was ON.  Once I turned it OFF everything worked fine.  Success!